# QGis plugin: problems after updating resources.qrc file with QtDesigner - No module named 'resources_rc'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pycharm

I'm developing a plugin for QGIS 3.32.3 with Python 3.9, starting from a base created with Plugin Builder 3, but after modifying the resources.qrc file with QtDesigner, the plugin is no longer loaded and I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources_rc. I tried to convert the file with pyrcc5 but unfortunately I get several errors, both if I try to do the conversion from the Python console and if I try by opening cmd in the folder where the qrc file is located. I have seen several solutions to the problem published, even if they refer to versions from years ago, I have not been able to apply them.
Now I can't move forward with the development of the plugin, I can't figure out the problem. How can I do this?

Small update, I managed to convert the qrc file to py using the OSGeo4W Shell and with the path in the plugin directory I executed the command: pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources.py, but I still have the problem of the resources_rc module not being found .

Comment: please paste the content of your resources.qrc file here, maybe there's some clues in it.

Comment: Here is the contents of the resources.qrc file:
'''<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/plugins/Retabo3" >
    <file>grafica/logo_1.png</file>
    <file>RTB3_icon.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>'''

I have a doubt, can it hit the Makefile!? Should this also be changed?
Also in my "name_plugin.py" I don't import any resourcdes module, I left everything as created by plugin builder and the reosurces.qrc file modified with QtDesigner.